# Understanding non-standard arithmetic models.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

I am reading Enderton's Logic Book and I can't understand the proof that there is a non-standard arithmetic model. The proof is typical using the compactness theorem:

First we expand $\mathcal{L}$ with the constant $c$ and then we consider $\Sigma=\{0<c,\text{S}0<c,\text{SS}0<c,\cdots\}.$

Then by the compactness theorem it is possible to prove that $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{N})\cup\Sigma$ has a model $\mathfrak{M}$.

Finally we "ignore" the interpretation of the constant and then we have a model $\mathfrak{M}_0$ elementarily equivalent to $\mathfrak{N}$. We can also show that $\mathfrak{M}_0$ and $\mathfrak{N}$ are not isomorphic because the universe of $\mathfrak{M}_0$ contains the infinite number $c^\mathfrak{M}$.

What I don't understand is that if there is a non-standard element in $\mathfrak{M}_0$ it would be true that:

$\mathfrak{N}\nvDash(\exists x)(\forall y)(y<x)$

$\mathfrak{M}_0\vDash(\exists x)(\forall y)(y<x)$ Since $c^\mathfrak{M}$ would be a witness.

And the structures would not be elementarly equivalent.

Comment: I think you mean $(\exists x)(\forall y)(y \leq x)$, not $(\exists x)(\forall y)(y < x)$. The latter sentence is never satisfied in any strict linear order, since it implies $x < x$.

Comment: The fact that it *has* to be elementarily equivalent is a good guide to understanding what nonstandard models look like. For instance you can show they must have order type $\mathbb N + L\times \mathbb Z$ where $L$ is a linear order. (And can further restrict the structure of $L$ depending on what the language is.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$c^{\mathfrak{M}}$ is not a greatest element of $\mathfrak{M}$. For example, $S(c^{\mathfrak{M}})$ is larger than it.

Comment: Or its square. Or $(2^c)^{\frak M}$. Or...